# Analog connection with DVI-I cable

Tags: analog, connector, video

I bought a DVI-I male to DVI-I male (dual link) cable, and found out that there is no conductivity between the both ends of analog pins. Particularly, in the following diagram, the pins C1, C2, C3, C4, and 8 on the two ends do not seem to be connected to anywhere.

[image]

My understanding is that  DVI-D cables do not have analog pins, and the purpose of DVI-I is to be able to connect to any kind of DVI devices as long as the devices on the both ends are compatible. Is my understanding wrong? If I am wrong, what is the purpose of a DVI-I cable where there is such thing as DVI-A and DVI-D cables? If I am right, I am planning to complain the seller about the cable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A DVI-DL cable contains two data connections:

> The DVI-D and DVI-I connector includes provision for a second data link, but few devices implement this. In those that do, the connector is sometimes referred to as DVI-DL (dual link).
>   ***-- Wikipedia***

This is so that two devices (or one extra-high bandwidth device) can be connected to one DL capable port.

A cable with Dual Link wiring can use either DVI-D or DVI-I but not DVI-A as its connector.

It is unlikely that anyone under normal circumstances would want to use Dual Link with analog, since the whole point of the Dual Link is to give two digital connections.

For this reason it is common for Dual Link cables to not bother with the analog signals for both cost and cable bulk reasons.

So why does it have a DVI-I plug and not a DVI-D plug?  Because the video cards tend to have DVI-I or DVI-A sockets.  The flat pin in the center is larger on DVI-I and DVI-A than it is on DVI-D.

Comment: I'm reading this post on a dual-link monitor right now!